# Get-Service results always displaying last

Tags: powershell, service

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to allow my customers to run a quick health check on a server to see if there is anything obviously wrong when something is not working properly.  One of the things I want to do is to check the status of the services required for our program to run.  I also wanted to make sure the PowerShell window stays open for them to be able to view the results, so at the very end of the script I added the line:

```
read-host "Press Enter key to close"
```

So this is what I'm working with:

```
#Check status of Services

write-host "Checking status of Product and IIS Services" -BackgroundColor DarkRed
get-service | where {$_.DisplayName -like '*Product*'} | select DisplayName,Status
get-service | where {$_.DisplayName -like '*iis*'} | select DisplayName,Status


write-host "Health check complete"
read-host "Press Enter key to close"
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to display the services until the very end:

```
Checking status of Product and IIS Services

Health check complete
Press Enter key to close: 
DisplayName                              Status
-----------                              ------
Product Service 1                       Running
Product Service 2                       Running
Product Service 3                       Running
Product Service 4                       Running
IIS Admin Service                       Running
```

Unfortunately, this defeats the purpose, as now things are not only out of order, but the PowerShell window closes immediately after the services are displayed.  Any idea how to get these to display in the order they're listed in the script?

Comment: Do. Not. Mix. `stdout`. and. `Write-Host`.  If you must, utilize `| Out-Host`

Comment: Bah, I mix them all the time. Pretty sure that truly makes me incorrigible...

Comment: @EBGreen If you mix them, you have no right to complain about incongruent outputs then.

Comment: Can we get @TheIncorrigible1 as moderator up in here please? :-D

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I know. :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I was thinking more of a grey text that appears with common problems as you're trying to post a powershell question. I AM THE GREY TEXT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will provide what you want while also being more accurate (less ambiguous).

```
Write-Host 'Checking status of Product and IIS Services.' -BackgroundColor DarkRed

Get-Service -DisplayName '*Product*','*iis*' |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName,Status |
    Out-Host

Write-Host 'Health check complete.'
Pause
```

Comment: You win!  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ChristopherCass If you want to change the colors, you can also replace `Out-Host` with `Write-Host` in the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
write-host "Checking status of Product and IIS Services" -BackgroundColor DarkRed
$list += get-service | where {$_.DisplayName -like '*iis*'} | select DisplayName,Status
$list += get-service | where {$_.DisplayName -like '*expl*'} | select DisplayName,Status

write-host "Health check complete"
Foreach ($item in $List) {
    Write-Host $Item.displayName - $item.status}
read-host "Press Enter key to close"
```

Comment: That's closer...  It looks like it's trying to put it into the correct spot now, but instead is throwing an error

    Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: @ChristopherCass The reason for that is due to his dash in the `Write-Host` argument being treated as subtraction.